# How to give docker container access to each others?

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, gitlab, containers

So far I made 2 docker container using [Docker Engine](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/) and [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) for a CI proof of concept. The first one is Jenkins and the other one is Gitlab CE.

Here are the version

```
Docker version 19.03.6
docker-compose version 1.25.4
```

and I have a `docker-compose.yml` that works perfectly fine to launch both containers

```
version: "3"

services:
  gitlab:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    container_name: "gitlab-ci"
    restart: "always"
    hostname: "gitlab.example.com"
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    volumes:
      - "/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab"
      - "/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab"
      - "/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab"
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
    external_url "http://gitlab"
  jenkins:
    image: "jenkins/jenkins:lts"
    container_name: "jenkins-ci"
    restart: "always"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    volumes:
      - "/home/USER/jenkinsci_docker:/var/jenkins_home"
```

However the both seems not to be able to communicate between each others,

because I cannot add the Repository URL in Jenkins and I have the following error:

[image: Jenkins screenshot]

I checked and the URL of my local Gitlab CE container works on the host http//:localhost:8081/root/simple-java-maven-app

I am using Ubuntu if it may help.
Thanks for reading if I can provide any more information feel free to ask me

Answer (score 0):

Add a the following to the Jenkins service section:

```
    jenkins:
    ...
      links:
        - gitlab
```

This will make the Gitlab container available at `http://gitlab:8081/...` [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links)

You could also add a virtual network, but since it's just two containers I'd recomend this.